# обосновано ли использование тире в конструкции "для вас ...(чтот-то)"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли тире в конструкции "для вас "КАМаЗ" и нужно ли оно в обратном прочтении: "КАМаЗ" для вас"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно по-разному. Решайте по наличию паузы, по тому, нужна она вам или нет.

Интересно, что при инверсии тире менее вероятно.